# Powershell match file name and move

Tags: powershell

I am trying to move files from one directory to another using powershell based on the file name.

The structure is (letters_ID_L-INT.*)

The ID is usually 7 characters long and has about 4 file with different extentions.

Usually VH_ID_P-INT.* The VH can change but is usually 2 letters. Example files would be. VH_ID_P-100020WW.txt HR_ID_V-10202334AA.PDF The ID would be the same in both files

The source destination is always the same but the output will change based on how many groups have been proccessed.

Once 10 matches have occurred move to folder 2 then folder 3 ect.

```
$Source = 'x:\Path\Path'

$Desination = 'x:\Path\desination\destination folder 1'

Foreach ($File in $source) {
$File.Name -match '(*_INT_*.*)';
```

Got a bit stuck here.

Comment: What does `INT` mean in your filtering example? Your file name examples don't match that.

Comment: Ignore the first and use the examples provide as that is more clear

Comment: If this is to be a regular thing, enterprise-wide for say all file servers, why script this. Use the enterprise tool MS provides on Windows server to do this. It's a service call FSRM. You not only can discover and move files by name, but by content as well.   It's called [FSRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/fsrm/fsrm-overview).

Answer (score 0):

Using folder 1, 2, 3.. and so on can be achieved by using two simple counters within your foreach counstruct:

```bsh
$i = 1
$j = 1

foreach ($File in $source) {
    $j++

    if ($j -eq 10) {
        $i++
        $j = 1
    }

    $Desination = "Path\Folder $i"
}
```

$i will change when 10 items are processed

To answer or help with regex i need more information. `[a-z]+` might be of help to represent any character from a-z with one or more repetitions. This includes Uppercase as PowerShell is not case sensitive per default.

Comment: Hi, its usually VH_ID_P-INT.*
The VH can change but is usually 2 letters.

Example files would be.
VH_ID_P-100020WW.txt
HR_ID_V-10202334AA.PDF


The ID would be the same in both files

Comment: A valid regex for this can be ```"\w{2}_\w{2}_\w-\d+\w{2}\.\w+"```. You can look ip the syntax at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions . ```\w{2}``` means two "word charakter", ```\d+``` means 1 or more "number" characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is where I got up to.
Throws a error: The process cannot access the file because it is beign used by another process.

```
    $Source = 'M:\1'

$i = 1
$j = 1

foreach ($File in $source) {
$File.Name -Match '([A-Z]+_{32}_[A-Z0-9])'
    $j++

    if ($j -eq 10) {
        $i++
        $j = 1
    }
    move-item $File -Destination $Desination
    $Desination = "M:\2 $i"
}
```

Comment: `{32}` does not mean what you think it means here. Since `-match` uses regex, `{32}` would mean match the previous match 32 times. So it would be looking for 32 underscores. If you want case-sensitivity, you should use `-cmatch` instead.

Comment: Ah okay, I was looking for the 32 to be the length of the value, should I use 0-9 instead?

Comment: If you want to match 6 digits, you would use `[0-9]{6}`. If you want 6 or more digits, use `[0-9]{6,}`. If you want 0 to 6 digits, use `[0-9]{0,6}`.

Comment: Relative to file moves. Sure, you must always check for the in-use (aka owned by another process - primarily this is Office docs and the like, not text files. ) before making decisions on what to do. There are a few ways to determine if this file is locked by a process.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your ...

> ***[This is where I got up to. Throws an error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.]***

... You can refactor your code to check for file locks and process only those that are not, and/or close them before you do.

Point of Note:  Closing open files, can/will cause file corruption/data loss. So, don't just randomly do this.

```
$Source = 'M:\1'

$i = 1
$j = 1

foreach ($File in $source) 
{
$File.Name -Match '([A-Z]+_{32}_[A-Z0-9])'
    $j++

    if ($j -eq 10) 
    {
        $i++
        $j = 1
    }

    Try
    {
        move-item $File -Destination $Desination -ErrorAction Stop
        $Desination = "M:\2 $i"
    }
    Catch {$PSitem.Exception.Message}
}
```

Or adding something like the below to your effort.

```
Clear-Host
# Remove non-Locked file and show screen output
'D:\temp\abc.txt', 'D:\Documents\Return To Sender.docx','D:\Temp\nonexistent.txt.' | 
ForEach{
    try   
    {
        $TargetFile = (New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $PSitem).Open(
                                            [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, 
                                            [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, 
                                            [System.IO.FileShare]::None
                      )
        $TargetFile.Close()  
        Remove-Item -Path $PSItem -WhatIf  
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]{$PSItem.Exception.Message}
    catch {$PSItem.Exception.Message}
}

# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\temp\abc.txt".
Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 'D:\Documents\Return To Sender.docx' because it is being used by another process."
Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "Could not find file 'D:\Temp\nonexistent.txt'."
#>

Clear-Host
# Remove non-Locked file and silence screen output
'D:\temp\abc.txt', 'D:\Documents\Return To Sender.docx','D:\Temp\nonexistent.txt.' | 
ForEach{
    try   
    {
        $TargetFile = (New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $PSitem).Open(
                                            [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, 
                                            [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, 
                                            [System.IO.FileShare]::None
                      )
        $TargetFile.Close()  
        Remove-Item -Path $PSItem -WhatIf 
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]{$null = $PSItem.Exception.Message}
    catch {$null = $PSItem.Exception.Message}
}
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\temp\abc.txt".
#>
```